# Best way to hide a loading gif if the user clicks the browser cancel button?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Currently I have a kendo menu with a javascript function that pops a loading gif.

```
 Html.Kendo().Menu()
                .Name( "menu" )
                .Orientation(MenuOrientation.Vertical)
                .Items( items =>
                {
                    items.Add().Text( "Company Info" ).Items( cInfoItems =>
                    {
                        cInfoItems.Add().Text( "Long Load" ).Url("/Controller/ActionMethod").LinkHtmlAttributes(new{ onclick="return LoadingGif();"});

                    } );


<script>
    function LoadingGif(){
        $('#divLoading').show();
    }
</script>
```

The issue is that while the View is rendering if the user clicks the browser cancel button the gif never hides.  What's the most graceful/slick way to handle this?

Comment: Does the abort event work? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/abort I saw it is in chrome as an available breakpoint.

Comment: @MikeCheel Correct me if i'm wrong, but wouldn't that event need to be tied to a specific element in a View?  What I really want is a way to detect if the browser stop button is pressed while the ActionResult tied to the kendo menu is in the process of executing.

Comment: I tried applying it to the body in my own test and no dice. I couldn't get it to trigger.

Comment: @MikeCheel well that's a bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Damn! This is an old post but still remains unanswered? Anyway, for those who have visited this page and scrolling for an answer, One way in which you can handle this is,

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    // Hide the model or a div; whatever you are using
    $(".modal").hide();
    //listen for the submit button click
    $("#myForm").submit(function (event) {
        $(".modal").show();
        // set a timeout to hide the gif
        setTimeout(function () { $('.modal').hide(); }, 2500);
      });
    });
```

That is, adding a timeout.
Not the best way though!.